# Python almacenar en listas

Tags: python-3.x

**Programa que captura N numero de calficaciones y calcula el promedio 
indicar promedio, alumnos aprobados y reprobados**

**Requiere almacenar los promedios de cada alumno asi como tambien los nombres de los alumnos,
debe imprimir al ultimo, el nombre su promedio y si aprobo o reprobo(Ojo con listas)**

*El codigo que llevo es la primer parte pero no me explico con claridad lo de la segunda parte, Gracias por cualquier ayuda o comentario!*

```
import os
alumnos = 0 
calificaciones = 0
contador_alumnos = 0 
contador_cal = 0
paso = 0
npaso = 0

alumnos =  int(input("Cuantos alumnos se van a capturar: "))


for alumno in range(alumnos):
promedio = 0
cant_cal = int(input("Cuantas calificaciones para este alumno: "))
calificacion = 0
for cal in range(cant_cal):
    calificacion += float(input(f"Captura la calificacion[{cal}]: "))
promedio = calificacion / cant_cal

if promedio >= 7:
    paso += 1
else:
    npaso += 1
print(F"El promedio del alumno{alumno} es {promedio} ")
print(F"Los alumnos aprobados son{paso} alumnos reprobados son {npaso}")
```

Comment: Bienvenido @YisusKras a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: En el código posteado te sugiero que se trabaje con listas o diccionarios para ir almacenando la información y pueda ser indexada, te dejo este enlace [Diccionarios en Python](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/diccionarios-en-python/) para que puedas trabajar más el código que has posteado y puedas agregar datos como algunos alumnos y algunas notas para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Adicionalmente en el bucle `for alumno in range(alumnos):` alumnos es un entero, este tendría que ser por ejemplo una lista, para que se pueda iterar por ella, en tal sentido te dejos este enlace para que lo revises: [Listas en Python](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/listas-python/)